# Mobile App Sound Design

Tags: app

hello SSD.

I've had a relative amount of success doing sound design and editing for short films and feature lengths, however i am looking to break into the mobile app sound design market and i was wondering if anyone had any experience or advice they would be willing to share?

many thanks in advance

Tom

www.teejsound.com

Answer (score 1):

Know some developers.

I don't know how most acquire their audio, but many use stock sounds, because they're cheap and easy to audition and download, or they may have a contact or they may just do the sounds themselves or they may seek someone from Google. But contacts to mobile app developers are surely a key.

There's nothing technically surprising. Only that the devices have small mono speakers and thus it's advisable to use reference monitoring while deciding on EQ and loudness.

Also, "mobile apps" is not really that big of a market. Most apps don't even have sound.
Mobile games would be a different and a more substantial market.